# Convey 'bleeding edge'

Tags: traduction, anglais, technologie

Bleeding edge, derived from cutting edge, has a negative connotation. Bleeding edge implies that a product or service is so new that its adoption could be harmful.

> Bleeding edge refers to a product or service, usually involving technology, that is available to consumers but is so new and experimental that it has not been fully tested and, consequently, may be unreliable. Early adopters could experience design flaws and bugs that have not been observed by the developers. It is also a given that bleeding edge products may never gain mainstream acceptance.
> https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/bleeding-edge.asp

Is there a way to convey this turn in French?

Comment: Considering that it's a very recent term, I doubt that there's an equivalent in French.

Comment: You can find example translations on the internet. Look at how the French [original sentence](https://theconversation.com/un-scientifique-chinois-a-t-il-fait-naitre-les-premiers-bebes-crispr-107619) that has been translated into "put China at the bleeding edge of biotechnology innovation".  (*The Conversation* usually has very good translators).

Comment: You might also consider revising the meaning you give  for cutting edge which is very restricted and not the one usually found in dictionaries ([e.g.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bleeding%20edge)), or used in the media where it is used as being just one step ahead of cutting edge.

Comment: When used with the meaning you give context is what matters. Look at how  ["it was not at the leading edge of technology but at the bleeding edge of technology"](https://www.ourcommons.ca/DocumentViewer/en/36-1/house/sitting-172/hansard) has been translated into  ["n'était pas à la fine pointe de la technologie, mais au bord du gouffre"](https://www.noscommunes.ca/DocumentViewer/fr/36-1/chambre/seance-172/debats), which I find good in this context.

Comment: @None Il y a un truc excellent dans cet exemple, c'est que _être à la fine pointe_ est un régionalisme (Qc.) d'après ce que je [vois](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/lexies/%C3%AAtre%20%C3%A0%20la%20fine%20pointe%20de) et ça veut dire la même chose qu'[_être à la pointe de qqc._](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pointe/62009#164951) mais morphologiquement ou le fait qu'il y ait deux mots fait que ça donne l'impression, mais l'impression uniquement, d'être plus fort que juste _pointe_ peut-être, un peu comme _cutting edge_ par rapport à un _edge_ moins « coupant » pour ainsi dire...

Comment: Typing error in [comment above](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/48687/convey-bleeding-edge?noredirect=1#comment97389_48687) where  I meant to write  revising the meaning you give for **bleeding** edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy : "expérimental" or "prototype" or "pionnier" or "faiseur de tendance". It really depends on the context and the exact sentence. But all of these words carry the "bleeding edge" that something is the new toy, but also not yet a tried and reliable industry standard.